# Como usar datos de un session Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hola buenas tengo el siguiente código donde me logueo y guardo los datos en un `Array`. Quiero saber cual es la forma para poder datos en una vista.

```
function check_database($pwd){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $result = $this->m->login($username, $pwd);
    if ($result){
        foreach($result as $row){
            $sess_array = array(
                'Codigo' => $row->Codigo,
                'Nombre' => $row->Nombre,
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }    
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Usuario Invalido');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Aquí cargo la vista:

```
public function menu(){
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('main/index', 'refresh');
    }    
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
}
```

Vista:

```
<?php include ('header.php'): ?>
//Aqui ver los datos de la persona logueada
<?php include ('footer.php'): ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obtener las variables de sessión se tienen 3 métodos segun la documentación oficial los cuales son los siguientes:

```
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$name = $this->session->name
$name = $this->session->userdata('name');
```

En tu caso quedaria de la siguiente manera:
    Controlador:

```
function check_database($pwd){
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $result = $this->m->login($username, $pwd);

    if ($result){
        foreach($result as $row){
            $sess_array = array(
                'Codigo' => $row->Codigo,
                'Nombre' => $row->Nombre,
                'logged_in' => TRUE);
            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Usuario Invalido');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Cargar vista:

```
public function menu(){
    if (!$this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {
        redirect('main/index', 'refresh');
    }
    $this->load->view('dashboard');
}
```

Vista:

```
<?php include ('header.php'): ?>

$codigo = $this->session->userdata('Codigo');
$nombre = $this->session->userdata('Nombre');

echo 'Datos del usuario';
echo 'Código: '.$codigo;
echo 'Nombre: '.$nombre;

<?php include ('footer.php'): ?>
```

Documentación oficial:

> https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Gracias mirare la documentación, pero mi duda es que lo guardo de la siguiente manera `$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);`  como deberia cargalo en la vista.

Comment: A ok, para guardarla no se hace de esa manera edito la pregunta para que veas como se hace.

Comment: Leyendo la documentación lo puede solucionar! Gracias

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta marcala como aceptada, en la paloma debajo de los votos!!