# Puedo utilizar la session de php puro en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

tengo la siguiente duda tengo un login en php puro donde guardo las variables en un session como usuario y tipo. Aparte tengo un programa pero esta en Codeigniter y realizo un diferente login para el acceso de este. Mi duda es si puedo usar la session de php puro y que codeigniter las puedas lear, ya que dentro del codeignter tengo validaciones por tipo de usuario.

Saludos.

Guarda la session asi  `Login Codeigniter`

```
  $sess_array = array(
                        'Codigo' => $row->Codigo,
                        'Nombre' => $row->Nombre,
                        'Tipo' => $row->tipo_usuario,
                        'Area' => $row->Area,
                        'DescArea' => $row->DescArea
                    );

$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

Hago uso de ella en codeigniter

```
        $session_data   = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['Codigo'] = $session_data['Codigo'];
        $data['Nombre'] = $session_data['Nombre'];
```

Como lo usaria en PHP puro?

Comment: Si todo esta en el mismo sitio, por que no usas mejor el login de codeigniter? te facilita ciertos aspectos después. De todos modos, supongo que tienes que poder. Si cuando haces tu "login" redirecciónas al método con el que se hace login en codeigniter y le pasas los 2 parámetros que tengas en las variables php, deberías poder iniciar. Si no siempre puedes intentar crearte una ruta a mano en codeigniter, que lo que haga es lo que comentaba antes pero hecho más "a mano".

Comment: @DiegoMartin Como lo usaria en el codigo de PHP puro para llamar la variable `$this->session->userdata('logged_in');`

Comment: [Aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/170840/como-usar-datos-de-un-session-codeigniter) ya tienes la respuesta